# Torsion in the Lie algebra cohomology of gl(n,Z)

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, lie-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology

What is known about the Lie algebra cohomology $H^*(\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})$? After passing to $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficients, the question is classical:  $H^*(\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{Q}),\mathbb{Q})$ is the free graded-commutative $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra on generators in degrees $1,3,\dotsc,2n-1$.  So really this is a question about torsion in $H^*(\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})$. Can one find an explicit integer $M_n$ which kills the torsion?

An old paper of Koszul ([Homologie et cohomologie des algèbres de Lie](http://www.numdam.org/articles/10.24033/bsmf.1410)) identifies the Lie algebra cohomology ring of a reductive Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ over any field $K$, with the subring of the exterior algebra $\bigwedge(\mathfrak{g}^*)$ which is invariant under the adjoint action of $\mathfrak{g}$.  So a related question is to identify what this invariant algebra is, in the case that $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$.

Comment: TeX note: `\mathfrak` accepts an optionally multi-character argument, so, although `\mathfrak{g}\mathfrak{l}` works perfectly well, you can also just use `\mathfrak{gl}`.